# Xamarin Forms, how do I get the entered date from a datepicker to a format of your choice?

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

It works fine for a user when they use it, it is easy to work with (even though I would like to remove the year somehow) and that code looks like this:

```
var DatePickerXamlName = selectedDate;
        DatePickerXamlName.Format = "ddd, d:e MMMM";
```

How can I get the format to be the same when I put in the user entered info as a string? I have tried to do something like this but it is very messy and obviously not working;

```
App.ourDates = selectedDate.Date.ToString();
App.ourDates = selectedDate.Format = "ddd, d:e MMMM";
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can pass a [format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to DateTime.ToString();

```
App.ourDates = selectedDate.Date.ToString("ddd, d:e MMMM");
```

However, it's probably a better idea to store the value internally as a DateTime, and only convert it to a string for display.

In your specific case, you are binding your Label to ourSelectedDate, which is (presumably) a DateTime.  The binding will automatically use the default ToString() conversion for your locale to display the date.  If you want to override this, you can use the StringFormat parameter in your binding.

```
<Label Text = "{Binding ourSelectedDate, StringFormat='{0:ddd, d:e MMMM}'}"
 Font = "10" TextColor = "Black" YAlign = "Center" />
```

Comment: I still get the users entered date in the listview as "ddd, d:e MMMM" which means that it cannot find the data I guess?

Comment: You need to post the code that binds your ListView and any DataTemplate you're using.

Comment: You can specify a FormatString in a binding, but since you haven't shown your code it's difficult to give you an applicable example

Comment: <ListView x:Name = "EmployeeList"   RowHeight = "50"  
 IsPullToRefreshEnabled = "true" >

 <ListView.ItemTemplate>

 <DataTemplate>

 <ViewCell>

 <StackLayout>

 
 <Label Text = "{Binding ourSelectedDate}" Font = "10" TextColor = "Black" YAlign = "Center" />


 </StackLayout>



 </ViewCell>


 </DataTemplate>

 </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>

Comment: It does not seem to work. I still get it as "2015-12-12 00:00:00" I use the code u typed : "{Binding ourSelectedDate, StringFormat='{0:ddd, d:e MMMM}'}"

Comment: is ourSelectedDate a DateTime or a string?

Comment: It is a string, because otherwise I cannot store it in my database (because I work with strings there)

Comment: Ahhh, it works now!! Instead of doing App.ourDates = selectedDate.Date.ToString("ddd, d:e MMMM"); immidietly I stacked them up as different variables. I guess it is the same method when u work with time? Thanks alot man!!

Answer (score 1):

I think the DatePicker can takes all of the standard C# string formats.

http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Example :

```
App.ourDates = selectedDate.Date.ToString("{0:ddd, MMM d, yyyy}");  // It will be Sat, Dec 12, 2015
```

It's better to store the value as DateTime itself, and you can alter it into a particular format at the time of appearing.